# Is there a more pythonic way to find the end of a pixel list in an image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have an image that contains an unknown amount of colored pixels in RGBA value. I need to find the end of the pixels with pixel data that is not (0,0,0,0).

I solve it with a rather lengthy loop, and I wonder if this can be done shorter and faster, in a more pythonic way? (I use PIL Image library btw)

```
pixels = mask.load()
end_x = 0
end_y = 0
for x in range(size_x):
    for y in range(size_y):
        if pixels[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 0) and x % size_x and end_y == 0:
            end_y = y
        if end_y != 0:

            y = end_y - 1
            if pixels[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 0) and end_x == 0:

                #be sure this is not a single empty pixel
                if pixels[x+1,y] == (0,0,0,0) and pixels[x+10,y] == (0,0,0,0) and pixels[x+20,y] == (0,0,0,0):
                    end_x = x
```

Comment: so you want the index of pixels whose values != (0, 0, 0, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your PIL Image to a Numpy array:

```
im = Image.open('input.png').convert('RGBA')
nim = np.array(im)
```

Then use this to get the x,y coordinates of anything non-zero:

```
np.nonzero(np.any(nim,axis=2))
```

That gives you 2 arrays (one of all the X-coordinates and one of all the Ys), so you may want to get the first element of each like this:

```
Xs, Ys = np.nonzero(np.any(nim,axis=2)) 
x = Xs[0]
y = Ys[0]
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the question, I am unable to understand what the problem is, and the code of the OP is kinda cryptic too

Comment: @VasuDeo.S OP's image is RGBA and has a black border, i.e. RGBA(0,0,0,0). OP wants to find x,y coordinates of first non-black pixel - I think.

Comment: Yes! Works. Fantastic. Thanks a lot! Tried to upvote but apparently I have not enough "points" to vote.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Can you please provide a PIL equivalent of this code too, which is efficient. As i am not familiar with numpy. Thanks in advance

Comment: @VasuDeo.S It is not easy to do in PIL and PIL really goes hand-in-hand with Numpy which is what you need to use for anything that is large-scale number-handling in Python such as image processing. I commend the following paper to you as I learned everything I know about Numpy from there https://scipy-lectures.org/_downloads/ScipyLectures.pdf

Comment: actually in my case this works:

    x = Xs[-1]
    y = Ys[-1]

these are the coordinates of where values start to be (0,0,0,0)

Comment: Are you maybe starting with a BMP file?

Comment: it's a .png file